# Result of one query, input for other query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to get information from two tables **users** and **results**.

users table has

```
id, name, email, password columns etc.
```

and results table has

```
id, user_id, last_attempt_time etc.
```

The result table gets populated every time a user takes a quiz.

I want to display user_id,name and last_attempt_time but my query returns oldest time and i have no idea how to solve this problem.

```
SELECT u.id,u.email,u.name,u.joined,r.last_attempt_time FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN results r
    ON u.id=r.user_id
    GROUP BY u.id
    ORDER BY u.id ASC
```

Comment: I don't see a `quiz_id` in the information you provided for the `results` table, and don't see why such a field would be relevant to `user.id`.

Comment: See the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: @Uueerdo sorry my mistake, It is user_id instead

Comment: Lynne's answer below, with a corrected join condition, should give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT u.id,u.email,u.name,u.joined,MAX(r.last_attempt_time) AS LastAttempt
FROM users u left join results r on u.id=r.quiz_id
GROUP BY u.id,u.email,u.name,u.joined
ORDER BY u.id ASC
```